# Why did President Snow want to use Peeta to kill Katniss?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hunger-games, the-hunger-games-mockingjay-1

I clearly don't understand the motivation for President snow of the ***Hunger Games: Mockingjay*** and the leader of the Capitol (Capital) to hurt **Katniss Everdeen** by using **Peeta** on screen and getting Peeta to say all these things about a ***ceasefire*** but when the rescue team from ***District 13*** go to the Capitol and rescue some remaining tributes from the ***Hunger Games*** that have been held ransom, they are helped out by some supporters in the Capital itself. But when they get Peeta back to 13, he attacks Katnis by strangling her.

Why would President Snow just let Peeta be captured by District 13 rescuers and let 13 take him?
Also to add: why would Peeta have saved 13 from the bombing from the Capital and basically saves them, when he is rescued he attacks her?
what is going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**He wants to destroy the symbol of the revolution.**

Think back to the end of the first film.

Katniss saves Peeta's life by threatening to eat the poisonous berries, and thus kill them both. In doing so she forces the government's hand, making Snow look weak.

Katniss then has to pretend to love Peeta, and this love is shown to the public. Snow even taunts her with it, knowing the love is false.  But he doesn't reveal it publicly, because he knows he can use it against her.

Katniss then becomes the face of the revolution.

By showing Peeta switching sides, and by having him be the one to kill Katniss, Snow will regain his lost power. He will once again appear to be the man in charge.

Part of this comes from the Quarter Quell, where Katniss (to the public at least) apparently abandons Peeta.

It's also a massive personal and demoralising blow against Katniss.  Even if Peeta fails, Snow hopes to break Katniss' spirit, and in doing so destroy her, and the revolution with it.

He fails, because he doesn't count on Katniss actually coming to love Peeta.

Answer (score -2):

President Snow was playing on human instincts/ feelings. Both Katniss and Haymitch were so caught up in the fact that Peeta was being tortured that they (and everybody else) didn’t focus on what they did to him or what he might be like when they get him back. Snow knew that when Peeta was rescued Katniss would be so caught up in just being able to see him that her guard would be down.
I understood it better when Collins mirrored it with Gale and Beetee’s bombs. 1. The first bombs go off and people’s loved ones/ people in general get hurt (Peeta clearly being tortured) 2. The nurses/ paramedics/ loved ones come rushing in to help them (Katniss and Haymitch both running to see Peeta when he’s rescued) 3. The second bomb goes off killing the wounded from the first bomb and any paramedics or loved ones that have rushed in with their guard down (Peeta turns into a mutt and kills Katniss and catches Haymitch, the only other person at this point to also run in, by surprise). Idk if that makes sense.

Peeta does three interviews, I don’t know about the second (in the movie he hasn’t been hijacked yet but the book it’s unknown??) but by the third Peeta has been hijacked so when he’s doing the interview mutt Peeta doesn’t understand why he should warn 13 so normal Peeta has to fight mutt Peeta’s mind to get his words out. But when he’s rescued by 13 he’s been hijacked and tortured more (most likely) and knocked out by gas.  So when he wakes up and sees Katniss (the only person he’s targeted to kill) mutt Peeta wins out.